# Storing an html page into a php variable

Tags: php, html, ajax, json, storing-data

Hi i'd like to store a dinamically generated(with php) html code into a variable and be able to send it as a reply to an ajax request.
Let's say i randomly generate a table like:

```
<?php 
$c=count($services);
?>
<table>
<?php
for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$services_global[$i][service] ."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$services_global[$i][amount]."</td>";
 echo "<td>&euro; ".$services_global[$i][unit_price].",00</td>";
 echo "<td>&euro; ".$services_global[$i][service_price].",00</td>";
 echo "<td>".$services_global[$i][service_vat].",00%</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

I need to store all the generated html code(and the rest) and echo it as a json encoded variable like:

```
$error='none';
$result = array('teh_html' => $html, 'error' => $error);
$result_json = json_encode($result);
echo $result_json;
```

I could maybe generate an html file and then read it with:

```
ob_start();
//all my php generation code and stuff
file_put_contents('./tmp/invoice.html', ob_get_contents());
$html = file_get_contents('./tmp/invoice.html');
```

But it sounds just wrong and since i don't really need to generate the code but only send it to my main page as a reply to an ajax request it would be a waste of resources.
Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion: "please phrase a more specific question" ...

Comment: I would also suggest not to generate html straight in code. Better to use some kind of template engine (just php includes will work too). My favorite one is Twig (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to store it in a file, you can just use the proper output buffering function

```
// turn output buffering on
ob_start();

// normal output
echo "<h1>hello world!</h1>";

// store buffer to variable and turn output buffering offer
$html = ob_get_clean();

// recall the buffered content
echo $html; //=> <h1>hello world!</h1>
```

[More about ob_get_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Comment: The thing is that if i echo the html then it will be taken as a reply to the ajax request won't it? I'd need to generate the html without echoing it or something like that.

Comment: You can store the html in the variable and use it whenever you'd like. You're not forced to echo it until you need it...

Comment: In order to store the html into the internal buffer with ob_start(); i need to generate and echo it.

Comment: Once you've called `ob_start()`, echo will send text into the output buffer rather than onto the page.

Comment: @g0dl3ss, yea I'm not sure where you're struggling to understand how `ob_start()` works.  After `ob_start()` is called, `echo` will not actually output anything.  Instead, the output is captured to the output buffer.  From there, you can decide how/when you want to use/display it.

Comment: It looks like the html code is printed anyway even if i `ob_start()`.
I'm going to do some tests, thanks for the support.

Comment: It's working now, it didn't work cause i had some html written closing the php tags and not echoed through php.
Now the html code doesn't show and it gets stored into `$html` using `ob_get_clean();`.
Exactly what i was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if the data is so much expensive to regenerate then I would suggest you to use [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php).

Otherwise I would go regenerate it every-time or cache it on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    ob_start();
    $store_var = $store_var.getdata($i); // put here your recursive function name
    ob_get_clean();
}

function getdata($i)
{
    ?>
    <h1>
    <?php
      echo $i;
    ?>
    </h1>
    <?php
    ob_get_contents();
}
```